# Android app calculate until 2^28

Tags: android

Hello everyone i'm trying to figure up why does my calculate app cannot work with numbers bigger then 2^28.

The next num after the biggest is the smallest. Now I understand that the problem is with the definition of my variables but its an integer and at c++ integer variables are 8 bits numbrer that allows me to calculate 2^32.. so how do I get ridd of this bug?

Comment: "c++ integer variables are 8 bits" - I don't think so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I solved the problem. If you want to do an app that calculates extreme numbers change the variables you use to "double" variable that can calc numbers until 2^64